# Targeting the color of modal backdrop over layer v4 mui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the backdrop color of a mui v4 modal, and I am getting a gray layer on top of backdrop instead sure, it's default behavior but how to remove the shaded div , there is a div if I delete it will give me the clean color but don't know how to target I doubt its paper, any idea how to get rid of this shade or target that color value instated of targeting the backdrop ??

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  backDrop: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  
  
  <Modal
      className={classes.backDrop}
      open={context.modal.bool}
      aria-labelledby='modal-modal-title'
      aria-describedby='modal-modal-description'
   >
      {modalsBody}
   </Modal>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this `<Modal BackdropProps={{style: {backgroundColor: 'white'}}} />`

Comment: @KeatonBenning please post answer it is working

Comment: @KeatonBenning also if you can explain why targeting style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the [documentation for the modal](https://mui.com/api/modal/) we can see that there is a BackdropProps property. This property uses a style object for its value.

```
<Modal BackdropProps={{style: {backgroundColor: 'white'}}} />
```